# How to make contrast-colored slices in a pie-chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, pie-chart

I have a hard time displaying the slices of this pie chart in a clearer manner. The continual shades are difficult to follow. How do I color the slices with contrast colors next to each other? For example, the S3conv would be nicer with red, blue and yellow instead of two green's and one blue... Thanks very much!

Graph clarification:
Each pie represent one experimental plot. - Rot.Herb
Totalweight = sum of the weight of all weeds presented in the plot

The code I used for this chart was

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


weedweights<-data%>%
  select(-ends_with("No"))%>%
     gather(key=species, value=speciesmass, DIGSAWt:UnknownmonocotWt)%>%
     mutate(realmass= (10*speciesmass) / samplearea.m.2.)%>%
     group_by(Rot.Herb, species)%>%
     summarize(avgrealmass=mean(realmass, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
     filter(avgrealmass != "NaN")%>%
     ungroup()

ww2 <- weedweights %>%
  group_by(Rot.Herb) %>%
  mutate(totalweedweight=sum(avgrealmass)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(weedweights, aes(x=1, y=avgrealmass, fill=species, order=avgrealmass)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Rot.Herb) + 
  coord_polar("y") +
  ggtitle("Weedbiomass by crop phase and herbicide regime")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", vjust=2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  xlab("Weed dry biomass (kg per ha)")+
  ylab("Crop phase and herbicide regime")
```

[image: Here is the picture]

and here is the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jb6gjznyw2q16mx/AADcNKiicqkoHxpFYIsaTgk9a?dl=0)

Comment: You're trying to distinguish 25 different categories on the basis of colour. Pie charts are not a good way of displaying this type of data, and however you colour your key it's going to be very hard to determine what is what. However, if you wanted to stick with this you could use `scale_fill_manual` to manually pick colours.

Comment: Thank you. I can't do other graph because I have to display the relative weed biomass in each plot (Rot.Herb). Picking color manually would be much complicated because the number of weed species are unique for each plot.

Comment: Doing it automatically is also complicated for the same reason. Very hard to automatically (or manually) pick colours such that any combination of them that appear in the same pie chart will be "contrasting", especially since you do not know how many species per plot or which ones in advance, /and/ you require a consistent colour key for your 25 species across the 18 pie charts...

Comment: using `scale_colour_brewer` with one of the "Paired" palettes will help a little bit, but it won't get you all the way to 25 categories. I agree with the other commenters here that this is just a difficult problem.  Who is the target audience for this plot, and what do you expect/hope for them to glean from it?

Comment: Thank you all. I decided that I will keep the pies as they are. I wanted to print this chart to a poster to represent the diversity and relative mass of weeds per each plot.